# convergence of composite functions

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

1. If $f_n \to f$ pointwise on E, and $g: f(E) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $g \circ f_n \to g \circ f$ pointwise.
2. If $f_n \to f$ uniformly on E, and $g: f(E) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $g \circ f_n \to g \circ f$ uniformly.

Are the above statements true? If not, can anyone give counterexamples?

Comment: You assume $g\circ f$ is well defined, but are the  $g\circ f_n$ well defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that $E$ is a metric space and that $g$ is defined at least on the image of all of the $f_n$.

For 1, because $E$ is a metric space, $g$'s continuity implies sequential continuity.

For 2, it's not true.  We could take something like $f_n(x) = x\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ defined for $x\in(0,1)$, which converges to $x$ uniformly, because the error term is always $x/n<1/n$.  But then let $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.  Then your error term, $g\circ f_n(x)-g\circ f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$.  And no matter what your $\epsilon$ or $n$ is, there is some $x$ for which the error term is larger than $\epsilon$.

Comment: There is one typo in your solution. $f_n(x) = x+x/n$ converges uniformly to $f(x) = x$ (not $1/x$).

Comment: For 2, I got $g(f_n(x))-g(f(x)) = \frac{1}{xn}$ because $g(f_n(x)) = \frac{1}{x}(1+\frac{1}{n})$ and $g(f(x)) = \frac{1}{x}$ in your example correct?

Comment: @AdityaGhosh fixed.

Comment: @967723 $g(f_n(x)) = \frac{1}{x\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$

Answer (score 1):

1. is true, from definition of continuity. For any fixed $x,$ $f_n(x)$ is a sequence of points in $f(E)$, which converges to $f(x)$. Hence continuity of $g$ implies that $g(f_n(x))$ converges to $g(f(x)).$
2. is not true, here is a counter-example: Take $f_n(x) = x+1/n,$ $g(x)=e^x$, both defined for $x>0.$ Then, $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)=x.$ But $g(f_n(x)) - g(f(x)) = (e^{1/n} - 1) e^x,$ which does not converge to $0$ uniformly.

However, if you assume that $g$ is uniformly continuous, then you can show that $g\circ f_n$ converges uniformly to $g\circ f.$ 
Because if $g$ is uniformly continuous then for any $\varepsilon>0, $ there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|s-t|<\delta$ holds, we have $|g(s) - g(t)|<\varepsilon.$ Since $f_n$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $N$ such that for every $n\ge N$ we have $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x) - f(x)|<\delta,$$ which implies $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |g(f_n(x)) - g(f(x))|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: For the second question, what is $f(x)$ in that your example?

Comment: The example that I gave earlier was not correct, so I deleted that and added a new (counter)example.